# X-Axis is not fully taking the width in date time chart in high charts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using high charts lib to render date time column chart. But x-axis is not taking the exact starting value for the chart. In below example we need to set the bar width before `12th NOV x-axis` value

```
chart: {
            type: 'column',
            width : 709,
            marginTop : 100,
            reflow: false
        },
        exporting: {
          enabled: false
        },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
            colors: ["#00ACE6", "#EA8939", "#2D8093", "#EB5C6A", "#D9A300", "#1B7CDE", "#8D69E0", "#378A4E", "#4F5A65"],
      xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
          month: '%e %b',
          year: '%b'
        },
      },
      yAxis: {
        allowDecimals: false,
        min: 0,
      },
      plotOptions: {
        column: {
          stacking: 'normal'
        },
        series: {
          animation: false
        }
      },
        series:[{"name":"sent","data":[],"stack":"sent","_colorIndex":0},{"name":" received","data":[],"stack":"received","_colorIndex":1},{"name":"1 sent","data":[[1511136000000,1],[1510531200000,1],[1510444800000,1]],"stack":"sent","_colorIndex":2},{"name":"1 received","data":[],"stack":"received","_colorIndex":3},{"name":" made","data":[[1510531200000,1],[1510444800000,2]],"stack":"sent","_colorIndex":4},{"name":" received","data":[],"stack":"received","_colorIndex":5}], //Server data
        loading: {
          style: {
            marginTop: "-25px"
          }
        }

    });
```

js fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/L94731ge/5/

Could you please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding `startOnTick` for `xAxis` maybe correct your chart

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
            startOnTick:true,
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
      month: '%e %b',
      year: '%b'
    },
  },
```

please check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MBehtemam/jLhmcyv7/)